# Computing a New Variable from 2 Categorical Variables

Tags: r, variables, factors, recode

I would like to calculate a combined variable for sex and gender. I have each variable in R as integers. For example, if sex=1 and gender=1, then newvariable=1. How do I do this in R? There is no mathematical calculation involved because I would like to create the rules for how sex and gender will be combined.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I recommend the ifelse function (which is different from the if function).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If you take the WHO classification of race being biological and gender socially constructed, then you can use ifelse as proposed in a comment above. I use sex=1 for female!

```
ifelse(sex == 1 & gender == 1, "Female",
   ifelse(sex == 2 & gender == 2, "Male", "Transgender"))

ifelse(sex == 1 & gender == 1, 1,
   ifelse(sex == 2 & gender == 2, 2, "Other"))
```

With dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
             sex = c(1,2,1),
             gender = c(1,2,2))
df$new_variable <- ifelse(df$sex == 1 & df$gender == 1, 1,
                           ifelse(df$sex == 2 & df$gender == 2, 2, "Other"))
```